401 with valid API Key (Authenticating with Open Api 3)
I have a custom Migration set in Drupal 10, I tested it with a local JSON file and it works but when I connect to a remote API I'm getting the following error:

401 Unauthorized response: {"type":"/error","title":"Request not authorized.","status":401,"detail":"Full authentication is required to access this (truncated...) "

I've tested with the following CURL and it returns as expected:
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "api-key: xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx" https://xxx.elsevierpure.com/ws/api/x

But I get a 401 when I add the following to my migration profile:
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: https://xxx.elsevierpure.com/ws/api/persons
  headers:
    - accept: "application/json"
    - api-key: "xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx"
  item_selector: items

The Pure API uses OpenApi 3

Maybe the headers are case-sensitive? Accept rather than accept?

The issue is missing 'basic' authentication:
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  headers:
    Accept: 'application/json'
    api-key: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx'
  authentication:
    plugin: basic
    username: xxx
    password: xxxx

